# Adding a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to add a ListView to a Fragment. I created a FrameLayout in my `activity_main.xml` and then created 3 fragments (Home, Tags, Settings). What I did was create a bottom navigation view and created 3 frame layouts for the mentioned fragments.

I searched the whole web on how to add a ListView to a Fragment, but whatever code they say is deprecated. I just want to add a ListView to the settings fragment. The code is below:

```
package com.bhiruva.dashboard.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.bhiruva.R;

public class FragmentSettings extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public FragmentSettings() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static FragmentSettings newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentSettings fragment = new FragmentSettings();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
}
}
```

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bhiruva.dashboard.fragments.FragmentSettings">

</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me with the updated code for doing this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstand. But you should be able to just add a `ListView` in `fragment_settings.xml` ...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but I wasn't able to get it till now, with the answer at the bottom. All the code I searched on the web was deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you got the fragment to show on screen successfully and you just want to add a simple `ListView`. Here's how you do it:

1- Add the `ListView` to your fragmnet xml with an id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

2- Get a reference to it in `onCreateView` of your fragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        ListView listView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        return contentView;
    }
```

3- Create a Custom Adapter for your `ListView` that extends `BaseAdapter`:

```
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        List<String> items;

        public CustomAdapter(List<String> items) {
            super();
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return items.get(i).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
            textView.setText(items.get(i));
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

I created a simple one here that only makes hosts a list of strings and displays each with a TextView, but you can replace it with whatever you want.

4- Set the adapter of the `ListView` to your custom adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        ListView listView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // sample data
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            list.add("Item "+i);

        CustomAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(list);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return contentView;
    }
```

Done. You get a ListView in the fragment with all the items. As others have pointed out, ListView is not preferred when you have a large list of items, it's bettter to use RecyclerView in that case.